# How can I get LESS to output RGBa colour definitions?

Tags: less

Less & css

```
@white: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);

.color {
  color: @white;
}
```

Output

```
.color {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

For some reason I need to use RGBa in the LESS compiled output. How can I keep the RGBa in the output?

Comment: Btw. what could be a reason to output a non-transparent color as rgb***a***?

Comment: @seven-phases-max Possibly for the sake of consistency with other partially transparent colours.

Comment: Why care of "consistency" of the compiled CSS file (as soon as it is valid)? The consistency of the source code is what is important (that's what is for human reading, the output CSS is for machine eyes only and should never be read by humans except certain debugging cases).

Comment: i want the color code consistency, but now i think force use same RGBa color code not a good idea :(

Comment: A thought - maybe you don't want the colour to apply in IE 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *interpolated strings* instead of `rgba` *function*:

```
@alpha: 1;
@white: ~'rgba(255, 255, 255, @{alpha})';

.color {
  color: @white;
}
```

Output:

```
.color {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [escaping](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping) to make Less to skip value parsing and evaluation:

```
@white: ~'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
```